# JS Underscore: array of dicts in pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

Is it possible to sort array which looks like this:

```
array = [ 
    {'title': 'a',
      'text': 'info a1'},
    {'title': 'b',
      'text': 'info b1'},
    {'title': 'c',
      'text': 'info c1'},
    {'title': 'a',
      'text': 'info a2'},
    {'title': 'a',
      'text': 'info a3'},
    {'title': 'b',
      'text': 'info b2'}
]
```

Sorting by pairs - that is - all unnecessary dictionaries passed to the end of the array
to like this:

```
array = [ 
    {'title': 'a',
      'text': 'info a1'},
    {'title': 'a',
      'text': 'info a2'},
    {'title': 'b',
      'text': 'info b1'},
    {'title': 'b',
      'text': 'info b2'},
    {'title': 'a',
      'text': 'info a3'},
    {'title': 'c',
      'text': 'info c1'}
]
```

Also i use Underscore if it can help. The array also contains other data. I need to display all the elements that have a pair. And all the elements that without a pair  in the end of the list . I think it would be easier if sort the array before displaying it.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Did you look at http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy?

Comment: btw, your objects are not valid.

Comment: @rednaw sordBy not sort by pairs

Comment: please add valid data and why the last `'a'` goes after `'b'` and before `'c'`. do you have some more properties which are relevant for it?

Comment: @NinaScholz Other info just for display - This does not affect the sorting

Comment: please, please, add a concise example of data.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry ( im little nerves because not know how do that

Comment: @NinaScholz this data better?

Comment: please define *all unnecessary dictionaries* with the data, you have quoted.

Comment: @NinaScholz seems it's bad idea - it is not possible to do without additional requirements or the array's restructuring - I will look for another way out thanks for your attention and responsiveness

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you consider to use a flag for `necessary`, then you could sort truthy values of `necessary` to top and then sort by `title`.

```js
var array =[
        { title: 'a', text: 'info a1', necessary: true },
        { title: 'b', text: 'info b1', necessary: true },
        { title: 'c', text: 'info c1', necessary: false },
        { title: 'a', text: 'info a2', necessary: true },
        { title: 'a', text: 'info a3', necessary: false },
        { title: 'b', text: 'info b2', necessary: true }
    ];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.necessary - a.necessary || a.title > b.title || -(a.title < b.title);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: No, it's not exactly what need - I need sorting by pairs - the third line with "a" should go end - this is the complexity

Comment: Sorry, i added it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in array is wrong and shall contain a column for property..

```js
function custom_compare(a, b) {
  if (a.text< b.text)
    return -1
  if (a.text > b.text)
    return 1
  return 0
}
array = [ 
{'title': 'a',
  'text': 'info a1'},
{'title': 'b',
  'text': 'info b1'},
{'title': 'c',
  'text': 'info c1'},
{'title': 'a',
  'text': 'info a2'},
{'title': 'a',
  'text': 'info c0'},
{'title': 'b',
  'text': 'info b2'}
]

array.sort(custom_compare);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: need sorting by pairs - the third line with "a" should go end

Comment: I saw your edit, @Lola but still your data is wrong. If you have correct data you can change a.title to a.text and all such reference in my example or use `_.sortBy(array, 'text'));` in example of @Nina-scholz. What i mean is if you are sorting based on "Text" then provide actual string of text, that will put a in 2nd last line. Even "manual" sorting your sampe won't result in what you are asking

Comment: @Lola I edited my answer to show you what I meant by wrong data. Now I changed text of third a to `"info c0"` and then sorting based on text resulted in the order you want. And probably that is what you want, I _assume_ (and you are not able to provide sample data)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not know what exactly the information will be in the text field

Comment: So then that is correct @Lola. You shall sort "dynamically" and NOT always fix a to 3 or 2 or so. A shall be located based on what value comes in "text" property. Otherwise it's NOT sorting but some fixed order.